# How can I print the names of students with scores larger than 50 from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

```
objects = {
"ALI_ELDIYAB": "80.80",
"BILAL_HASSAN": "78",
"DANIA_RAHMANI": "71.20",
"DANIEL_AIGBE": "78",
"HAMD_ALFARES": "72",
"KHALED_AL_SHAIBANI": "74",
"LINA_ISSA": "70",
"LUMA_ABDELAZIZ": "78",
"MARIAM_BASHER": "44",
"MOHAMMED_BINDAGHER": "74.80",
"NADAY_ALHAMMALI": "77.60",
"NISRIIN_ABDI": "67.60",
"OMAR_HAFEZ": "66.80",
"OMAR_SLEIMAN": "83.20",
"OMAR_MOUSTAFA": "77.60",
"RAHAF_IBRAHIM": "68.80",
"RASIL_ALSAKKA": "82",
"SETYA_GHAHREMANI": "82",
"SHARMAAKE_HANDBO": "59.20",
"YAHYA_ABDELBAGI": "64",
"YOUSIF_KASHWAN": "76.40",}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
for i in objects:
    if objects.values < '70':
        print(i)
```

Comment: Well ... `'6000' < '70'` is true ... you are comparing strings - not numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```py
for name, value in objects.items():

    score = float(value)

    if score > 50.0:
        print("{}'s score is pretty good".format(name))
```

First think is that by using the `items()` method of the dictionary you can iterate over the key and value for all entries.

Second, you have to convert the score into a comparable type like an integer or float (in this case float seems to fit better) to compare it.

Some reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you have here is that all of the values in your dictionary are strings. Please see my example below of what you are looking for:

```
objects = {
   "ALI_ELDIYAB":"80.80",
   "BILAL_HASSAN":"78",
   "DANIA_RAHMANI":"71.20",
   "DANIEL_AIGBE":"78",
   "HAMD_ALFARES":"72",
   "KHALED_AL_SHAIBANI":"74",
   "LINA_ISSA":"70",
   "LUMA_ABDELAZIZ":"78",
   "MARIAM_BASHER":"44",
   "MOHAMMED_BINDAGHER":"74.80",
   "NADAY_ALHAMMALI":"77.60",
   "NISRIIN_ABDI":"67.60",
   "OMAR_HAFEZ":"66.80",
   "OMAR_SLEIMAN":"83.20",
   "OMAR_MOUSTAFA":"77.60",
   "RAHAF_IBRAHIM":"68.80",
   "RASIL_ALSAKKA":"82",
   "SETYA_GHAHREMANI":"82",
   "SHARMAAKE_HANDBO":"59.20",
   "YAHYA_ABDELBAGI":"64",
   "YOUSIF_KASHWAN":"76.40"
}

for i, ii in objects.items():
    if float(ii) < 70:
        print(i)
```

What this does is for each key and value in the dictionary, it will check if the value (in the type 'float') is under 70, then print.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
for i in object.keys():
    if float(object[i]) < 70:
        print("{} has a score of {}".format(i, object[i]))
```

This will convert the scores to numbers (specifically, floats, since you have non-integers there) and then you can check whether each score satisfies your conditions.